# how to make sqlite temporary data files .shm,.wal to be in user ownership rather than root

Tags: sqlite

I am accessing SQLite3 database as root user and my main database file is having some user ownership.
And I want that my temporary data files like .wal and .shm should be in same user mode as main database file.Because if these temp files are in root mode,some of my further application specific operations are failing.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks,
dcds

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the workaround to my problem. If we do data opening/locking operation as the user who owns the main data file from inside C code by using setuid(), then these temporary data files will be generated with the same ownership as the main database file.